# a function to count occurrences or frequency of an element and return an object but remove elements which occurs one and return the rest

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, javascript-objects

so i have this function

```js
function counting(arr) {
  result = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (!result[arr[i]]) result[arr[i]] = 0;
    ++result[arr[i]];
  }
  return result;
}

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 2, 6, 1, 8]
console.log(counting(arr))
```

i get this result

```
{ '1': 2,
  '2': 2,
  '3': 1,
  '4': 1,
  '5': 1,
  '6': 3,
  '7': 1,
  '8': 2,
  '9': 1 }
```

But what i actually want is the function to delete every element has has only 1 occurrence and leave the others with more than one occurrence like below

```
{ '1': 2,
  '2': 2,
  '6': 3,
  '8': 2}
```

Comment: so look over the entries and reduce it.

Comment: NB: simpler code for the loop: `let key = arr[i];  result[key] = (result[key] || 0) + 1`

Comment: @Alnitak replacing your code with the my loop  i get this as the result { '1': 1 }

Comment: no, it's for for inside of the loop, to replace the `if (!element) element = 0` test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with one loop, by having two separate frequency maps.

```js
function counting(arr) {
    const [freq, result] = [{}, {}];
    arr.forEach(i => {
        freq[i] = (freq[i] || 0) + 1;
        if (freq[i] > 1) result[i] = freq[i];
    });

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So loop over your result set and reduce it again.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,6,6,7,8,9,5,2,6,1,8]

const counts = arr.reduce(function (o, n) {
  o[n] = o[n] || 0;
  o[n]++
  return o
}, {})
const result = Object.entries(counts)
  .reduce(function (o, v) {
    if (v[1] > 1) {
      o[v[0]] = v[1]
    }
    return o
  }, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Just for fun: `const counts = arr.reduce((o, n) => (o[n] = (o[n] || 0) + 1, o), {});` - this uses the comma operator to avoid the explicit `return`.

Answer (score 0):

You can break it up into a couple functions:

1. A function to get the frequency of elements in the array.
2. A function that drops properties not greater than 1.

```js
const test = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 2, 6, 1, 8]

const frequency = arr =>
  arr.reduce((o, x) => {
    o[x] = (o[x] || 0) + 1
    return o
  }, {})

const dropSingleOccurrences = counts =>
  Object.entries(counts).reduce((o, [k, v]) => {
    if (v > 1) o[k] = v
    return o
  }, {})

const result = dropSingleOccurrences(frequency(test))

console.log(result)
```